# Stackdriver log-based metrics does not display the values as reported by logging

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

My goal is to base my metrics directly from log values. The problem is when I display them as graph it looks like they are distributed. How can I change it so that it displays the values from the logs?

[image: logging current sessions]

[image: values are distributed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Stackdriver doesn't work in that way, you shouldn't expect that Stackdriver shows you "52" in this case. Have a look at the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/) where "logs-based metrics can be one of two metric types: counter or distribution" and "counter metrics count the number of log entries matching" and "distribution metrics is to track latencies". You have to choose another tool for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you created this as a distribution metric, I would expect this to work.  Please take a look at this blog [post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/management-tools/stackdriver-tips-and-tricks-understanding-metrics-and-building-charts) to make sure you're using aligners and aggregators correctly.